# How do I scroll to s specific location in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have found one way which uses JS, but I would rather use CSS, which I think I had seen used before, but I cannot remember how. I what kind of CSS would I use to position the webpage inside and iframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an `anchor` in your `iframe`: `<a id="aBottom"/>`. Now, we will need that `anchor` that we added in your `iframe` and get `anchor`'s [`offsetTop`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html):

```
var position = window.frames["anchor_iframe"].document.getElementById("aBottom").offsetTop;
```

Now, set your `iframe` `scrollTop` with `position`

```
window.frames["anchor_iframe"].document.body.scrollTop = position;
```

**iframe-scroll-to-anchor-position.htm**

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function getThere() {
      var position = window.frames[0].document.getElementById("aBottom").offsetTop;
      window.frames[0].document.body.scrollTop = position;
  }
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="getThere();">Get me there!</button>
<br/>
<iframe src="loremipsum.htm" width="80%" height="510"> </iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

**loremipsum.htm**

```
<html>
<body>

<p>


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.

<br/><br/><br/><a id="aBottom" style="background:red;">can you see me!</a><br/><br/><br/>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi tempor rutrum neque, id tincidunt dolor euismod eget. Sed eget dui lectus, in scelerisque est. Cras in elit leo, ut egestas ante. Sed pharetra nisl quis tortor blandit ut aliquam massa euismod. Donec et dictum diam. Nam mollis libero eget quam dignissim eu viverra libero adipiscing. Sed tempor, metus semper pellentesque rutrum, ipsum mi molestie ipsum, sed viverra libero neque et velit. Fusce pulvinar erat non nisl suscipit sagittis. Nam commodo purus in velit luctus congue. Nam tincidunt congue eleifend. Donec ut mauris quis eros ullamcorper aliquam. Maecenas sit amet ligula quis lectus condimentum dictum. Donec sit amet nisi ac ante pellentesque gravida. Nulla interdum metus faucibus neque molestie cursus.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to do it on the same domain, you can use the following... Cross domain will violate js's same domain policy.:

You wait for the document to finish loading (to get the iframe ref) then wait for the iframe to finish loading (so that you can scroll without interference), then you use the scrollTo function.

```
document.onLoad = function() {
   var iframeEle = document.getElementById('iframeId').
   iframeEle.onLoad = function() {
      iframeEle.scrollTo(xCoord, yCoord);
   }
}
```

If you want a better way to add the onload events, jquery provides a more complete implementation which I would advise you use.

Comment: I am using two different domains. What I am trying to do is create a homepage with my email, news, fb, weather, etc all in one spot, and I really like Yahoo!'s news. The one that is titles "Today" on their homepage. So what I am trying to do is I have an iframe for yahoo.com, and I need to scroll it so that the today module is the only thing visible. Sadly, I cannot find an API for the "Today" module, so this is my only option.

Comment: Well, it's not exactly what you want to hear, but you could always use RSS? Then you can just use a google gadget to embed the feed on the page. To do this, you just do this http://www.labnol.org/internet/tools/embed-rss-feeds-add-html-websites-javascript/2515/

Answer (score 1):

But if you do that, you'll be loading the entire yahoo page (even ads), just to show a small section, nevermind the fact that everytime yahoo changes layout, you'll have to adjust the cropping and the rest of your page... couldn't you just use one of [their rss news feeds](http://news.yahoo.com/rss) instead?